# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) when submitting form

Tags: android, mongodb, react-native, axios

I cant seem to get a form to work, I get the error ***Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):***

I'm combining two components for a personal application, both work independently. The one is a working login form with MongoDB, the other is react-navigation with screens written by someone else.

```
import strings from "./strings";
//import styles from "./styles";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Platform,
  Alert,
  Image,
  ImageBackground
} from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { NavigationScreenProps } from "react-navigation";

import LoginForm from "../../../components/LoginForm";
import axios from "axios";
import baseUrl from "../../../baseUrl";
axios.defaults.baseURL = baseUrl;

class LoginScreen extends Component<NavigationScreenProps> {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "test@test.com",
      password: "secretPassword999",
      errorMessage: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSignIn = this.handleSignIn.bind(this);
    this.handleSignUp = this.handleSignUp.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(name, value) {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  async handleSignUp() {
    try {
      const { email, password } = this.state;
      await axios.post("/auth/signup", { email, password });
      this.handleSignIn();
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: error.response.data.message });
    }
  }

  async handleSignIn() {
    try {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: "" });
      const { email, password } = this.state;
      const result = await axios.post("/auth/login", { email, password });
      Alert.alert("", result.data.token);
      console.log(result);
      this.props.handleChange("token", result.data.token);
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: error.response.data.message });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require("../../../images/blur.jpg")}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            position: "relative",
            resizeMode: "cover"
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.headerText}> Title</Text>
          <Text style={styles.headerSmall}>Service</Text>
          <LoginForm
            email={this.state.email}
            password={this.state.password}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            handleSignIn={this.handleSignIn}
            handleSignUp={this.handleSignUp}
          />
          <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
          {/*<Image
          source={require("../../../images/image.jpg")}
          style={styles.logo}
        />*/}
          <Button
            buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
            title={strings.forgottenPassword}
            onPress={() =>
              this.props.navigation.navigate("PasswordResetScreen")
            }
          />
          <Button
            buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
            title={strings.loginTitle}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")}
          />
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#6B52AE" 
  },
  errorMessage: {
    marginHorizontal: 22,
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 44,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 0, 
    color: "#FFF",
    fontFamily: Platform.OS === "android" ? "sans-serif-light" : undefined,
    marginTop: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  headerSmall: {
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 20, 
    color: "#FFF",
    fontFamily: Platform.OS === "android" ? "sans-serif-light" : undefined,
    marginTop: 0,
    fontWeight: "200"
  },
  logo: {
    height: 210,
    width: 360,
    marginLeft: 51,
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
});
```

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at LoginScreen.handleSignIn$ (blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:87093:55)
    at tryCatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:21953:19)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:22128:24)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:21996:23)
    at tryCatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:21953:19)
    at invoke (blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:22029:22)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:22039:15
    at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:23231:14)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:23332:17
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/43e70a76-bca3-42a1-8a1f-44f14f5d8aeb:24654:21
```

Answer (score 0):

> this.setState({ errorMessage: error.response.data.message });
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

The `error.response` seems to be `undefined`.

If an error such as "Domain not found" occurs outside HTTP, `error.response` will be `undefined`.
Such errors sometimes occur even if implemented correctly, and should be considered in error handling.

The reason for access failure in your case is not clear from the information provided.
The `console.log(err)` will give you more information.

Comment: If I console log the error I get this 

TypeError: this.props.handleChange is not a function
    at LoginScreen.handleSignIn$ (blob:http://localhost:8081/2f7667e1-f4f5-4b2d-92b0-9714459ea15e:87096:28)
    at tryCatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/2f7667e1-f4f5-4b2d-

Comment: at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (blob:http://localhost:8081/5e61931b-8b9e-4fb0-a434-214cd066895e:22128:24)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (blob:http://localhost:8081/5e61931b-8b9e-4fb0-a434-214cd066895e:21996:23)

Comment: Changing `this.props.handleChange("token", result.data.token);` to `this.handleChange("token", result.data.token);` will resolve that error.